# Where to find the RPM file of GIMP for installation?

Tags: software-installation, rpm, gimp

I wanted to install GIMP just like installing it on Windows using the exe or msi file. Where can I find the RPM file so I can just issue the command

```
rpm -ivh gimp-2.8.14-x86_64.rpm
```

I like to install files as easy as that. Is it possible?

Comment: Unlike with Windows, it is typical for software packages to come from the distribution you are using, rather than directly from the software's authors. So, this will depend on what distribution you are using. Fedora? openSUSE? Mandriva? Something else?

Comment: *"I like to install files as easy as that."* -> Why would you bother when it is even easier to just `yum install gimp`?  Done.  What you are asking about is actually the awkward, difficult, and **totally pointless** way.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm used to installing software in offline mode. YUM needs internet connection so I like using the command RPM (the offline way).

Comment: You should have put that in your question; if you are doing something even slightly unorthodox, make it clear.  Right now, it *appears as if* you do not understand the basics of using a package manager.  So all apologies -- but I'll leave my comment for posterity lest you confuse someone else with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gimp doesn't provide compiled .deb or .rpm files, so if you want it and don't want to compile source code check the repositories of your distribution or go to sites as:

http://rpmfind.net/

http://rpm.pbone.net

Search for *gimp*, you will see a list of downloadable rpm files ordered by version, architecture and OS version.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the RPM then it will be in `~/downloads`, but if you installed it with cURL or wget then it is in the directory you downloaded it to. More information on the RPM's location and/or where you got it from would be helpful. 
If you do not know *where* it is, type `find / -name gimp-2.8.14-x86_64.rpm` into the terminal.
As for possibility, yes you can do `rpm -i rpmName`.